# Can I handle CellValueChanged and RowLeave in a specific order?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, event-handling

In my DataGridView I handle events when a *CellValueChange* occurs and different events when a *RowLeave* occurs. Now when BOTH occur at the same time (leaving the row after changing a cell) then only the *RowLeave* event seems to trigger (or it may trigger first and therefore make my *CellValueChanged* event do nothing?)

How can I force the DataGridView to handle my *CellValueChanged* event first, before handling the *RowLeave* event? Or, alternatively, how can I trigger some other code if **BOTH** events trigger (**AND**, not *OR*)?

I am using VB.Net but if you have an answer in C# I can work with that as well. This is not so much about the exact coding as it is about what to do.

Thank You!

Comment: I am having trouble understanding what the `RowLeave` event is used for. What is the `RowLeave` event doing that would affect the `CellValueChanged` event?

Comment: RowLeave is triggered if you change the current cell from one row index to another, i.e. when using the down key to get to the cell below the current one. What ends up happening is that if I change the cell before moving down to the next cell below, both events seem to trigger but not in the order I want. It seems like the CellValueChanged event triggers after RowLeave and thereby messing with what should happen on RowLeave. Ideally I want the CellValueChanged event to trigger on input and when I leave the row (key up or down) I want the RowLeave trigger to be the last event to be processed.

Comment: Your comment: _"It seems like the CellValueChanged event triggers after RowLeave and thereby messing with what should happen on RowLeave."_... The cellValue change will obviously fire second if the user changes the value in a cell then clicks on another row. AGAIN!.. What is happening in the row leave event that would be "messing with" what happens in the CellValue changed event?

Comment: To avoid this wasteful twenty questions back and forth. Why don't you show what both events are doing?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the easiest way to do this (at least in my case) is not using the *CellValueChanged* event but the *CellBeginEdit* event instead. They are not exactly the same but for my use *CellBeginEdit* works just as well.

The important thing is that editing a cell will cause my former *CellValueChanged* code to run and once I leave the row after changing the cell, **only** the *RowLeave* code runs. That's what I was after.

So, in short, not handling the value change but instead handling the cell going into edit mode does the trick.